# asp net webform textbox or razor textbox or html textbox to use? when to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webforms, html

i just learning c# asp net webform and webpage razor from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/), I find out that asp net webform have their own textbox syntax and razor does have too and html does have one too, which one I have to use and in what condition?

this one is asp.net webform

```
<form runat="server">

A basic TextBox:
<asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server" />
<br><br>

A password TextBox:
<asp:TextBox id="tb2" TextMode="password" runat="server" />
<br><br>

</form>
```

for razor

```
@Html.TextBox("TextBoxName")
```

and for HTML i think everyone know it. Gimme some suggestion, really confusing right now

Comment: It depends whether you're using MVC.

Comment: Webforms -> ASP Textbox Control, MVC -> Razor, Can use everywhere -> HTML

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC supports 2 view engines out of the box:

1. The WebForms view engine which is based on the ASP.NET WebForms syntax
2. The newer Razor view engine

Which view engine to use would really depend on many factors. Things like skill levels of the members of the team and existing codebase should be taken into account when making the decision.

This being said, I would very strongly discourage you from using the [`w3schools`](http://www.w3schools.com/) site for learning anything. If you want to learn ASP.NET MVC, the official [`asp.net`](http://asp.net/mvc) site should be a better place to get started.